# jest throws "No matching bindings" from inversify

Tags: jestjs, vscode-extensions, inversifyjs

I am developing a vscode extension using inverisfy container for DI. I have implemented tests using own test runner as mentioned [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/working-with-extensions/testing-extension#the-test-runner-script). This uses mocha as test runner, but i tried replacing mocha with jest by following this [issue](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-test/issues/37#issuecomment-700167820). When testing the extension, jest throws `No matching bindings found for serviceIdentifier` when trying to access an instance from inversify container. Though same code works with mocha test runner.

I believe this is because of how jest resolves the modules and I am not sure how to resolve this. any help would be appreciated.

Sample repo here: https://github.com/saravmajestic/vscode-inversify-jest